# Is it possible to calculate gain when there is current source?

Tags: gain

The following is from the book Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits (https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf) on Page 86.

Calculate the exact voltage gain of the circuit shown in Fig. 3.67.

[image]

Doing ac analysis for small signal.

[image]

We can use KCL because the current \$I_{D1}\$ and \$I_{D2}\$ are the same.
$$-Vp(g_{m2} + g_{mb2}) + \frac{V_{out} - V_p} {r_{o2}} = V_{in} g_{m1} + \frac{V_p} {r_{o1}}$$

It looks like impossible to calculate this gain since we have an unknown variable \$V_p\$.

Comment: Try to use the T-model and you will see that Vp/Vin = 1/gm2/(1/gm1) = gm1/gm2 thus, if gm1 = gm2 Vp/Vin = 1 and the Vout/Vp = gm2*rout. So you need to find rout.

Comment: @G36 But T model don't consider body effect \$V_{bs}\$

Comment: @internet Do you have any idea on where I am wrong?

Comment: Draw a full small-signal model so that we can see what you have done wrong.

Comment: @G36 Can you show me you  schematics for full small signal model?

Comment: Try to solve this circuit https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3xiB.png

Comment: @G36 Please take a look at my answer. It's the same as before

Answer (score 1):

The following is the full small signal analysis.

[image]

$$g_{m2} V_2 + g_{mb2} V_2 + \frac{V_{out} - V_p} {r_{o2}} =
g_{m1} V_1 + \frac{V_p} {r_{o1}}$$

$$V_{in} = V_1$$

$$V_{2} = -V_p$$

$$\Rightarrow -V_p(g_{m2}  + g_{mb2})  + \frac{V_{out} - V_p} {r_{o2}} =
g_{m1} V_{in} + \frac{V_p} {r_{o1}}$$

$$\Rightarrow -V_p(g_{m2}  + g_{mb2} + \frac{1} {r_{o2}} +\frac{1} {r_{o1}})  + \frac{V_{out}} {r_{o2}} =
g_{m1} V_{in} $$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_{out}} {r_{o2}} =
g_{m1} V_{in} + V_p(g_{m2}  + g_{mb2} + \frac{1} {r_{o2}} +\frac{1} {r_{o1}})$$

Still, unknown variable \$V_p\$ is there.

According to hints from @internet and @G36.

$$-V_p(g_{m2}  + g_{mb2})  + \frac{V_{out} - V_p} {r_{o2}} = 0$$

$$\Rightarrow -V_p(g_{m2}  + g_{mb2} + \frac{1} {r_{o2}}) = -\frac{V_{out}} {r_{o2}}$$

$$\Rightarrow V_p = \frac{V_{out}} {r_{o2} (g_{m2}  + g_{mb2} + \frac{1} {r_{o2}})}$$

Now we can substitute \$\frac{V_{out}} {r_{o2} (g_{m2}  + g_{mb2} + \frac{1} {r_{o2}})}\$ for \$V_p\$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_{out}} {r_{o2}} =
g_{m1} V_{in} + \frac{V_{out}} {r_{o2} (g_{m2}  + g_{mb2} + \frac{1} {r_{o2}})} (g_{m2}  + g_{mb2} + \frac{1} {r_{o2}} +\frac{1} {r_{o1}})$$

$$\Rightarrow V_{out} \biggl(\frac{1} {r_{o2}} - \frac{g_{m2}  + g_{mb2} + \frac{1} {r_{o2}} +\frac{1} {r_{o1}}} {r_{o2} (g_{m2}  + g_{mb2} + \frac{1} {r_{o2}})}  \biggl)=
g_{m1} V_{in}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_{out}} {V_{in}} =
\frac{g_{m1}} {\biggl(\frac{1} {r_{o2}} - \frac{g_{m2}  + g_{mb2} + \frac{1} {r_{o2}} +\frac{1} {r_{o1}}} {r_{o2} (g_{m2}  + g_{mb2} + \frac{1} {r_{o2}})}  \biggl)} $$

Simplify this equation, we can get the following.

$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_{out}} {V_{in}} =
- g_{m1} r_{o1} \biggl(r_{o2} (g_{m2} + g_{mb2}) + 1\biggl)$$

Comment: Vp = - V2. Just do nodal analysis with two nodes Vp and Vout and you can solve all.

Comment: Write another KCL equation at node Vout and then solve for Vout and Vp.

Comment: @internet what's the another equation? I have no idea.

Comment: it's KCL equation at the output node: `gm2*V2 + gmb*V2 + (Vout - Vp)/ro2 = 0` where `Vp = - V2`.

Comment: @internet How do you know the current it's 0?

Comment: It is KCL I_leaving_node = I_entering_node If all current leaving the node, and 0 current will enter the node.

Comment: @G36 Could you please have a look at my edited answer according to your suggestions?

Comment: @internet Could you please have a look at my edited answer according to your suggestions?

Comment: Your solution is correct you naild it. Good job.